# Bash trap conditional command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

can you help me understand this line I found in a script:

```
trap "[[ -d ${temp_dir} ]] && rm -rf ${temp_dir}" EXIT
```

The way I understand is, the trap command waits for EXIT signal and upon that, it removes the directory, if it exists.
Is this correct or can anybody educate me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct, although there are two changes I would make to the code itself:

1. `$temp_dir` needs to be quoted in the command to ensure it works correctly for any valid directory name. Let's say the value of `temp_dir` is `/tmp/some dir`. As is, the trap command will be

   ```
   [[ -d /tmp/some dir ]] && rm -rf /tmp/some dir
   ```

   which is incorrect, as the parameter is expanded before the `trap` command sets the error handler. Add some quotes to fix it:

   ```
   trap "[[ -d '${temp_dir}' ]] && rm -rf '${temp_dir}'" EXIT
   ```
2. Depending on when the value of `temp_dir` is set, you might consider putting the entire command in single quotes, so that `temp_dir` isn't expanded until the command is actually run:

   ```
   trap '[[ -d $temp_dir ]] && rm -rf "$temp_dir"' EXIT
   ```

However, it's usually simpler to keep the handler as simple as possible. Define a function to call:

```
clean_up_temp () {
    [[ -d $temp_dir ]] && rm -rf "$temp_dir"
}
```

and just call the function from the handler:

```
trap clean_up_temp EXIT
```

Comment: Also, note that there is no point in the `[[ -d $temp_dir ]]`.

Comment: Ah, unless you're worried that `$temp_dir` exists and is not a directory.

Comment: I debated whether to worry about that; presumably, `temp_dir` is being explicitly set to a directory name and used as such prior to exiting. As is, it doesn't guard against removing a directory that wasn't meant to be deleted, so at some point you have to assume that it names a directory that is meant to be deleted.